# Can I generate pulse with timer1 in normal mode in ATmega 2560 using TOV flag?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c

Timer have CTC and PWN for generating pulse. However if I want to generate pulse when timer reach its max level then using CTC or PWN is somehow not needed when the TOV is set whenever timer overflown. My idea is that the output pin will toggle whenever the TOV flag is set then TOV flag is cleared and wait for another overflown of timer. Here's my code in C though I not sure because I haven't understand how to handle each bit in register yet and I don't know how t simulate it in proteus.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
int main(void)
{
    TOV1 = 0; // clear timer 1 overflown flag 
    DDRD = 0xFF; // set port D as output
    TCCR1B = 0b00000001; // using internal I/O clock with prescaler 1 
    while(1){
        if (TOV1 = 1){
            PORTD ^= (1<<PORTD0); // toggle bit 0 on port D
            TOV1++; // clear TOV by adding 1 to TOV
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Must it be D0, or would either of B5 or B6 be acceptable?

Comment: Hi, the datasheet says bit 0 of PORTD is named PORTD0. So there's other ways to address bits or I/O port data register?

Comment: B5 and B6 are already associated with timer 1.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things awry here...

#### 1. Assignment instead of compare?

`if (TOV1 = 1){`

...probably should be...

`if (TOV1 == 1){`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817246/assignment-and-comparison

2. `TOV1` treated as a register when it is really a bit in the `TIFR1` register.

`TOV1 = 0;`

...should probably be...

`TIFR1 |= (1<<TOV1);`

(according to the datasheet, the flag is cleared by writing a 1 bit to it)

...and...

`if (TOV1 == 1)`

...should probably be...

`if (TIFR1 & (1<<TOV1) )`

#### 2. I don't think you can clear a bit by adding 1 to it

`TOV1++; // clear TOV by adding 1 to TOV`

...should probably be...

`TIFR1 |= (1<<TOV1);` // clear TOV bit`

(according to the datasheet, the flag is cleared by writing a 1 bit to it)

#### 3. Better way to toggle a bit

If you really want to toggle a GPIO pin, the PIN register is probably what you want. So...

`PORTD ^= (1<<PORTD0); // toggle bit 0 on port D`

...would be better as...

`PIND = (1<<PORTD0); // toggle bit 0 on port D`

You can Read more about this in the datasheet...

> 13.2.2 Toggling the Pin
>
> Writing a logic one to PINxn toggles the value of PORTxn, independent on the value of DDRxn. Note that the SBI instruction can be used to toggle one single bit in a port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about writing 1 in TOV flag. The datasheet said that "TOVn is automatically cleared when the Timer/Countern Overflow Interrupt Vector is executed. Alternatively, TOVn
can be cleared by writing a logic one to its bit location."

since I don't use interrupt so I just clear the bit manually

Comment: Agreed - fixed in answer above. The points I was trying to make are that (1) TOV is a bit in a larger register rather than a lvalue itself, and (2) you can't write a 1 to a bit by incrementing it. I totally understand the confusion because the treatment of bits in the AVR defines is not intuitive. with this in mind, people often make their code more readable by using macros like `setBit( TIFR1  , TOV1 )` rather than the equivalent `TIFR1 |= (1<<TOV1)` (both generate the same `sbi` instruction in asmbler code).

Comment: Thank you, but I want to ask that if it's possible to do so in order to generate waveform. After all, it's just how I think it'll work but I can't tried it because I have no physics microcontroller to try. I feel like _delay_ms can do same thing.